# javafx Minesweeper: how to tell between right and left mouse button input

Tags: javafx, mouseevent, eventhandler, minesweeper

I am working on a javafx Minesweeper game, and currently am only using left mouse button input.  I would like to use the right mouse button also so users can flag possible bombs.  I looked at the Oracle webpage for Button class, and it says:

"When a button is pressed and released a ActionEvent is sent. Your application can perform some action based on this event by implementing an EventHandler to process the ActionEvent. Buttons can also respond to mouse events by implementing an EventHandler to process the MouseEvent."

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html

Ive tried this several different ways, with no success.

Included is my current EventHandler code. If anyone can explain the best way to handle right/left mouse clicks, or point me in the right direction of where to find that information, it is greatly appreciated.

MineButton is a custom class that extends Button.  I would like on right click to mark as "m" and change cell color, and left click would remain the same.

```
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col <8; col++){

            MineButton button = new MineButton(row, col);
            button.setPrefSize(100, 100);
            button.setText("?");
            button.setStyle("-fx-font: 22 arial; -fx-base:#dcdcdc;");
            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    if ( button.isAMine() == true){
                        button.setText("B");

                        for( int row1 = 0; row1 < 8; row1++){
                            for ( int col1 = 0; col1 < 8; col1++){

                            if (mineButtons[row1][col1].isAMine() == true){
                                    mineButtons[row1][col1].setText("B");
                                    mineButtons[row1][col1].setStyle("-fx-   font: 22 arial; -fx-base: #dc143c;");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{

                        recursion(mineButtons, button.getX(), button.getY());

                    }       
                }   
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u wanna handle the MouseEvent use this code. It will work.

```
button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY){
//                  Type code to set flag here
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Added this to my code prior to my EventHandler, worked perfectly! Being able to mark mines made my minesweeper game that much closer to the original. Now I can add a timer, mines left counter, and a function to determine if player has one.  I think the function to determine a win will check to see if all spaces have been marked or uncovered except for mines.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot handle right clicks on a button by attaching an event handler on action event. Instead you need to add a handler to the mouse event:

```
button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if(mouseEvent.getButton().equals(MouseButton.SECONDARY)){
            System.out.println("Set flag on the button");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 scene.setOnMousePressed(event ->{
        if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            anchorX = event.getSceneX();
            anchorY = event.getSceneY();
            anchorAngleX = angleX.get();
            anchorAngleY = angleY.get();
        }
    });
    scene.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> {
        if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            angleX.set(anchorAngleX - (anchorY - event.getSceneY()));
            angleY.set(anchorAngleY - (anchorX - event.getSceneX()));
        }
    });
```

This code rotates a JavaFX group in a scene with a left mouse button and a drag. You can print the event.getButton to make certain your primary and secondary are working. I have tried many other ways including JavaFXtras. This is by far the simplest way to handle the primary and secondary mouse click events.

Comment: This code rotates a JavaFX group in a scene with a left mouse button and a drag. You can print the event.getButton to make certain your primary and secondary are working. I have tried many other ways including JavaFXtras. This is by far the simplest way to handle the primary and secondary mouse click events.